# get latest points for all users

Tags: mysql, sql

I am  getting the latest timestamp but with old scores .I am looking for latest timestamp with latest scores as response and only last one for each receiver . http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/07d11/1

```
 CREATE TABLE if not exists tblA
    (
    id int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment ,
    sender varchar(255),
    receiver varchar(255),
     msg varchar(255),
     date timestamp,
      points varchar(255),
     PRIMARY KEY (id)
    );

    CREATE TABLE if not exists tblB
    (
    id int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment ,
    sno varchar(255),
    name varchar(255),
     PRIMARY KEY (id)
    );


    INSERT INTO tblA (sender, receiver,msg,date,points ) VALUES
    ('1', '2', 'buzz ...','2011-08-21 14:11:09','10'),
    ('1', '2', 'test ...','2011-08-21 14:12:19','20'),
    ('1', '3', 'buzz ...','2011-08-21 14:11:09','10'),
    ('1', '3', 'test ...','2011-08-21 14:12:19','20'),
    ('1', '4', 'buzz ...','2011-08-21 14:11:09','10'),
    ('1', '4', 'test ...','2011-08-21 14:12:19','20');



    INSERT INTO tblB (sno, name ) VALUES
    ('1', 'Aa'),
    ('2', 'Bb'),
    ('3', 'Cc'),
    ('4', 'Dd'),
    ('5', 'Ee'),
    ('6', 'Ff'),
    ('7', 'Gg'),
    ('8', 'Hh');
```

sql :

```
select *, max(date)
from tblA a join
     tblB b
     on b.sno in (a.receiver) 
group by b.name
order by max(date) desc;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM (

  SELECT tblB.*, MAX(tblA.date) AS date
  FROM tblB
  JOIN tblA ON tblB.sno = tblA.receiver
  GROUP BY tblB.sno

) AS subset
JOIN tblA ON subset.sno = tblA.receiver 
            AND subset.date = tblA.date
```

The idea is to first select the rows you need (the subquery), by selecting the maximum date per record from `tblB`. Next you can join these records with the original table to fetch the scores.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the general idea.  You can work out the details

```
select field1, field2, etc
from table
join (
select id, max(timestamp) maxts
from table
where whatever
group by id ) temp on table.id = temp.id
where whatever
and timestamp = ts
```

The where whatever part has to be the same both places where you see it.